# Weighted Least Squares worse than OLS

Tags: estimation, least-squares, generalized-least-squares

I want to compare OLS with WLS. Therefore I came up with a polynomial. I evaluated the polynomial at 2000 datapoints and added GWN with a certain, varying, variance $\sigma_i$. Hence, I have the model

$$y=X\beta+\epsilon.$$

I use this generated date to estimate the parameters $\beta$ with OLS and WLS. As weight matrix in WLS I use

$$W=\textrm{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_N).$$
As error measure I use the MSE of the parameter. When I repeat the estimation a few times, the WLS delivers sometimes worse results compared to the OLS. Is this reasonable? I was of the opinion, that the WLS should always be better than WLS, especially in my case when I exactly know the variances and therefore the optimal weights.

Comment: What does "worse results" mean?  How are you measuring that?  ... keep in mind that the randomness of $\epsilon$, especially if "large" relative to $X\beta$, means that any set of parameter estimates is itself random, and consequently there's no guarantee that *for any single dataset* WLS will be "closer" in any sense to the true values than OLS.

Comment: If you want to minimize the sum-of-squared errors, then treating the errors as unweighted will render an optimal estimator with OLS. If, however, the variance is heteroscedastic, one must question whether the sum-of-squared-errors in the correct metric for model performance.

Comment: @jbowman like stated, I use sum of square error.

Comment: @AdamO Therefore I use varying variance, hence, heteroscedastic variance. Which error would you suggest? The sum of squared residuals $y-X\hat{\beta}$ with the estimation $\hat{\beta}$

Comment: @jbowman but in my case, WLS is BLUE where the B stands for best. Shouldn't that mean that WLS is better than OLS?

Comment: WLS *is* better than OLS when the variances are known.  That doesn't mean that it will be closer to the true values *for any given dataset* due to the randomness of the observations.  It's like saying Germany is better than Costa Rica at football, or Magnus Carlsen is the best chess player in the world; in any given game, however...

Comment: What does "best" then mean in this case, exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#:~:text=The%20theorem%20now%20states%20that%20the%20OLS%20estimator,expected%20value%20is%20always%20zero.%20Remark%20%5B%20edit%5D - look under the "Statement" for the line with "best linear unbiased estimator" in bold.

Comment: @Steradiant "Best" regards the efficiency of estimation of the $\beta$. It will usually give you better predictions when the model is correctly specified, but that's not always the case. Especially when a model is incorrectly specified, such as when Y does not vary linearly with X.

Comment: @Steradiant can you confirm that you REALLY set the weights to the residual standard deviation? You need to weight by the *inverse variance*.

Comment: @jbowman that's obviously exactly the point that's confusing me. The statement would suggest, that the MSE of the parameter - which I'm comparing - should be always smallest for the WLS.

Comment: @AdamO The model must be linear in the parameters, hence, WLS should be BLUE for a polynomial fit. And yes, I'm using inverse variance (so $W=Q^{-1}$ if I use the definition from wikipedia) from the noise $\epsilon$, hence, of the residual ($y-X\beta=\epsilon)$.

Comment: The key is the $E$ in front of the expression for MSE; it's the *expected* squared error that WLS minimizes (that's where the "Mean" part of Mean Squared Error comes in.)  To quote from the link:  "in other words it is the expectation of the square of the weighted sum (across parameters) of the differences between the estimators and the corresponding parameters to be estimated".  You are calculating the *actual* squared error, a very different thing.